# How to find Google Map API usage programmatically?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, usage-statistics, distance-matrix

I'm working on an `Application`, where I make use of the free version of the `Distance Matrix API` provided by `Google Maps`. I'm familiar with the usage limits of the same as well. Is there any method available to check the `Google Map API` usage programatically from the `Application`?

Comment: Google does provide all the usage statistics within the account. Is there any reason why you are trying to get it through code?

Comment: Yes. All the APIs are registered under our Organization's google account. One of our customer insists that, they want to have the requests made by their users, so that they can check the statistics and can plan accordingly to migrate to Google's Enterprise package.